# MySQL: How to fetch data with left-join if column contains multiple ids?

Tags: mysql, left-join

Assuming the following:

Table "info":

```
 id | target_ids
----|------------
 1  | 2
 2  | 
 3  | 4,1
 4  | 2,3,1
```

Table "targets":

```
 id | value
----|------------
 1  | dog
 2  | cat
 3  | tiger
 4  | lion
```

Using **left join**, I'm expecting something like this:

```
 id | target_ids | value
----|---------------------
 1  | 2          | cat
 2  |            | 
 3  | 4,1        | lion,dog
 4  | 2,3,1      | cat,tiger,dog
```

I've tried this:

```
select info.*, targets.value from info left join targets on info.target_ids = targets.id
```

The results I got is single values in "value" column

```
 id | target_ids | value
----|---------------------
 1  | 2          | cat
 2  |            | 
 3  | 4,1        | lion
 4  | 2,3,1      | cat
```

How can I get results as it's showing in the 3rd table? Thanks

Comment: I would say your tables are malformed. Your values are not atomic (see 1NF). Anyway: If you cannot change the tables you could create a temporary table from the data in the info-table and your the temp-table for the join.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use MySQL's [`FIND_IN_SET()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set) function as the join criterion:

```
SELECT   info.*, GROUP_CONCAT(targets.value) AS value
FROM     info LEFT JOIN targets ON FIND_IN_SET(targets.id, info.target_ids)
GROUP BY info.id
```

See it on [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/47854/1).

However, you would probably be best to [normalise](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) your data structure and store your info-target relations in a separate table:

```
CREATE TABLE InfoTargets (
  InfoID   INT NOT NULL,
  TargetID INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (InfoID, TargetID),
  FOREIGN KEY (InfoID)   REFERENCES info    (id),
  FOREIGN KEY (TargetID) REFERENCES targets (id)
);

INSERT INTO InfoTargets VALUES
  (1,2),
  (3,4), (3,1),
  (4,2), (4,3), (4,1);

ALTER TABLE Info DROP COLUMN target_ids;
```

Then you would do:

```
SELECT   info.id,
         GROUP_CONCAT(targets.id)    AS target_ids,
         GROUP_CONCAT(targets.value) AS value
FROM     InfoTargets
  LEFT JOIN info    ON   InfoID = InfoTargets.InfoID
  LEFT JOIN targets ON TargetID = InfoTargets.TargetID
GROUP BY info.id
```

If the order of targets is important (and might differ between each `info` item), you would need to create an additional `rank` column in `InfoTargets`.