# MySQL LEFT JOIN array, how do I return multiple rows?

Tags: mysql

I have the following code which has worked perfectly up until now:

```
$db->table = "horse_products as p";
$db->colums = "p.*, l.address as address, l.storename as supplier_name, c.title as cat_title, c.id_parent as id_parent";
$db->join =    "LEFT JOIN locations as l ON l.id = p.id_location"
                ." LEFT JOIN categories as c ON c.id = p.id_category WHERE c.id_parent = 8";
$db->orderBy = "p.id_location ASC, p.id_product ASC";
$items = $db->Select();
```

Previously `p.id_category` was an integer because only one category within the 'categories' table was allowed to be associated with a product. However today I decided to make `p.id_category` a comma separated array. The downside to this is that when I try to echo `$item['cat_title']`, I only get the first `c.title` within the `p.id_category` array. I would like to get the title for all the categories within `p.id_category`. Can anyone help me here? I hope that I've made myself understood, as a MySQL novice even getting my LEFT JOIN's to work was a challenge :-)

**EDIT:**

Sat myself down this morning to find a solution and found it in the answer to the following question: [MySQL: How to fetch data with left-join if column contains multiple ids?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10812861/mysql-how-to-fetch-data-with-left-join-if-column-contains-multiple-ids/). Thanks to all that helped.

Answer (score 1):

Bad idea beacause id_category should be unique integer value. If you want to have m:n relationship you need add another table with at least two primary foreign keys from tables that you want to have relationship. So in your case you will create table title_to_categories with primary key id_product and id_category. Id_product will be equals to p.id and id_category to c.id.

Comment: Thank you Filip. I am going to have to store these relationships in separate tables in the near future because my database is growing with ever more interrelationships. For now though I used `GROUP_CONCAT()` and `FIND_IN_SET()` which did the trick short term.

Comment: Ok for next time when your creating database in php thinking about model before you start using it. That will save you a lot of your time.

Answer (score 0):

Try with:

```
$items= $db->fetchAll();
```

And then go with foreach.